# Headless Torrent Server - Permission Denied

Tags: raspbian, server, pi-3, headless, permissions

**UPDATE 1:**

The permissions are currently set as follows:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service transmission-daemon stop

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/external_drive/

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 pi pi 16384 Jan  1  1970 external_drive

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/external_drive
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 16384 Apr 24 08:10 complete
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 16384 Apr 24 08:10 incomplete

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service transmission-daemon start

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Is that incorrect?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm trying to get my headless Pi3 torrent server running, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Any log files I could check to see why that error is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the permissions of the torrent directory:

```
sudo chown -R transmission:pi /mnt/
```

That is assuming the transmission-daemon is running from its own user, as suggested here:
https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts/initd

You can check that the transmission user exists by doing:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep transmission
```

and even check the user running transmission with a:

```
ps aux | grep transmission
```

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of transmission, a system user named transmission is created. The daemon runs using this user (cf https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts/initd).

In your setup, the user transmission does not appear to have write access to the folder in which the torrent is supposed to be saved.

One way to fix the issue would be to create a group of all users that should have access to the torrent, give write access to this group and include the transmission user in the group.